# How to setup VirtualBox network property to make ClickHouse callable on default port 8123 from master OS?

Tags: virtualbox, clickhouse

I made VM Ubuntu 16.04 with one network adapter "network bridge" and second adapter "internal network". ClickHouse DBMS installed by default.

Test call within slave Ubuntu `curl 'http://localhost:8123/'` returns `Ok`.
But the same call from master Windows host returns nothing :( 
Telnet and browser from master OS on `http://assignedIP:8123` returns `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.
At the same time pings slave Ubintu from master OS and opposite are successful.

How to setup VM's network properly to be able to call ClickHouse on port 8123 from master OS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found it!

Have to change 
`<listen_host>::1</listen_host>`
to
`<listen_host>::</listen_host>`
in `/etc/clickhouse-server/config.xml`

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check Unbutu firewall status. If it is up, bring it down and try.